# Why is someone discrediting my answers?

Tags: discussion

I answered some questions, but for some reason the answer police discredited my response and then removed it. Not just once, but a few times.

Can I get an explanation for what was wrong with my answers?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.

Comment: For the record, I downvoted, not JonW. As he mentions in his answer, the language in this post is not up to the expectations of this site.

Answer (score 12):

> I answered some questions, but for some reason the answer police discredited my response and then removed it. Not just once, but a few times.

None of your answers have been removed. Edited, yes, but not removed.

You have posted three answers that did little or nothing to actually answer the questions they were posted against. All three of these posts included a link to your website despite them not being relevant to the questions.

I deleted the blogspam links (although have still [left it in one of your posts](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/58385/what-is-the-advantage-of-drop-down-list-appearing-in-front-of-control-instead-of/59683#59683) as at least it is relevant to your answer - even though the answer itself is not useful in relation to the question asked).

I also put your "What are the websites you go to for reference" question on hold because it's not a suitable question for the site as there is no correct answer.

I have commented on all your posts explaining what I have done, and why. I am sorry if you disagree with these decisions, you're welcome to express your disagreement ([although you are still required to be nice](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) - something the language of your question here (pre-edit) was not).

On many other sites all your posts could have been deleted entirely as spam. I chose to give you the benefit of the doubt, but I may change my mind on that depending on how things here go.

Comment: @eeklipzz, Plus it is the **community** who are marking down your questions and who have supplied as much feedback on them to point out their issues. You should not take constructive feedback personally.